# ffmpeg loop not working keeps dropping frames after first loop

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, debian, raspberry-pi3

I did try out to make it work but got this error , i am new in this universe so i am asking for help. (drop frames after the first loop (as the timestamp will suddenly go back in time).)

```
[flv @ 0x117a2f0] Video codec rawvideo not compatible with flv
    Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented
```

My code now as i try to loop it, it stops after first loop, drops the frames...

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -f lavfi -re -fflags +genpts -i "movie=/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4:loop=0, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX
```

Code that i used before i tried to fix the loop issue but no other errors was:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -f alsa -i default -i /home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX
```

Anyone can help me also to get it looping? PS: i am streaming the video file in a combo with the desktop audio (as i play songs in QMMP for kids (kids radio project))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming the file in a loop with desktop audio to youtube works. Thanks to all!

```
ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video720p.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-xxxx
```

ffmpeg version 4.1, if you have a older ffmpeg version the loop command may not work...

Answer (score 3):

Use

`ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX`

stream_loop had a bug till recently, so use ffmpeg 4.1 or newer. The `lavfi` device will only output decoded frames, so you need to directly use the input file to avoid re-encoding.

For realtime streaming, all inputs should have the `-re` flag set.

Comment: ok i am on ffmpeg version 3.2.12 now, will try to update it, Thanks! Should it compile ffmpeg my self or? 
ffmpeg -version says ffmpeg version 3.2.12 , but if i try to install it it says ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1+rpt1).

Comment: Now i get a error: 
ffmpeg version git-2019-03-10-5ab44ff Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
Unknown input format: 'alsa'

Comment: Sorry did not see your link i already compiled it from git (couple days ago had the file still)

Comment: You'll need to build it with ALSA support. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi. Alternatively, if you have another device that can pipe audio to ffmpeg, you can go that route.

Comment: Again your answer did not update... will try that solution now...
got the ffmpeg from your link 
Here is a Screenshot from the error: [link]http://prntscr.com/myzuv2

Comment: So to be clear i understand it right, 
1. Compile ALSA library 2. Compile FFmpeg with libaacplus, libx264 and alsa-lib

Comment: You should skip libaacplus and libx264.

Comment: Skipped, libaacplus and libx264, compiled for 2 hours and got this error http://prntscr.com/mz3q4i , dont know where the mistake was... Any idea? I have tried to make install it anyway, same error, http://prntscr.com/mz3qqm

Comment: It's trying to compile x86 modules. What's your full configure script and output?

Comment: If i understand the questions right , from the tutorial provided i removed --enable-libx264  --enable-libaacplus from the configure script. I did the steps one more time and now ffmpeg is compiling, waiting to see what happens now, maybe it was my mistake doing something wrong, i learned like days how to compile.

Comment: It it doesn't work, try a prebuilt git package from https://github.com/wang-bin/avbuild

Comment: Here in the make install output https://file.io/Ux8ivo, i dont see any errors, but its like ffmpeg is not installed.

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -version
bash: ffmpeg: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ `

Comment: The configure output will have the install prefix. Check in /usr/local, /usr/local/bin

Comment: it sems ok now? `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-93394-g14eea7c47a Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
configuration: --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ `

Comment: Streaming and looping! Thanks Gyan Doshi you saved my day!

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to implement code to buffer it all (or only the music) before it goes to the stream server.

Comment: I got it to auto start on boot (if power failure), but i have one more barrier i cant find out how to do it, that is if the internet connection drops and ffmpeg stream stops how to reconnect it automatically? `ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video720p.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-xxx`

Comment: If ffmpeg assumes connection closed, then you have to kill ffmpeg and restart it.